# Injecting a custom die() handler into mod_perl SOAP handler

Tags: perl, mod-perl

We're using a `$server = SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Apache->new; $server->dispatch_with(...)` over here as a backend to a JS-based application. Should the underlying module die, it sends back a nice error message that gets displayed by the JS code.

The problem is, I would like more detailed messages (e.g. Carp::longmess), and a hard copy of those on STDERR.

How can I inject a custom exception handler into SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Apache with minimal code modifications?

(This is a large and old *project we can't afford to rewrite*, though honestly it deserves a rewrite).

UPDATE: here's a sample error message:

```
<soap:Body><soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Column 
'allocation' cannot be null at 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Tangram/Storage.pm
 line 686. </faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body>
```

I get a Tangram error but this is unlikely a bug in Tangram and anyway I need a full stack-trace. OTOH, the die message got into a SOAP  message which is not a normal die action so there's a handler *somewhere* -- which I want to customize a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error handler is located under `SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Server::_output_soap_fault`. Try a grep on `<faultcode>` in the perl INC paths.

Comment: Thanks, I was sooo afraid of taking apart standard modules that overlooked it. This should work. Still I would prefer an on_error handler there.

Comment: Why not put in a customisable error handler and submit a patch back to CPAN? If it gets accepted then its less maintenance for you to do in the future.

Comment: Wow, it was really in SOAP::Lite, and my on_fault() patch kinda works. Let's hope I get it into upstream.